# How to add data from contact form into Teamgate CRM?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to integrate "contact us form" on my website and integrate it with [Teamgate CRM](https://www.teamgate.com)so that all the data would fall into Leads section. On their website it is under [lead capturing](https://www.teamgate.com/solutions/lead-capturing/) section, but I can't seem to find the right explanation to do it..
Can anybody share step by step solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. At first you need to get an API key from your account settings.
2. Then you need to determine a form submission handler.
3. I have no idea which programming language or framework you are using. So, I’ll get you an example by cURL:

`curl -X POST \
    https://api.teamgate.com/v4/leads/ \
    -H 'x-app-key: YourApiKey' \
    -H 'x-auth-token: YouApiToken' \
    -F 'name=John Smith' \
    -F 'companyName=Example Company Ltd.' \
    -F 'jobTitle=Project Manager' \
    -F 'email=john@example.com' \
    -F 'phone=+1234567890'`

If you are developing on PHP, I think the best solution is to use [PHP SDK](https://github.com/teamgate/php-sdk):

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$teamgate = new \Teamgate\API([
    'apiKey' => 'YourApiKey',
    'authToken' => 'YouApiToken'
]);

$data = array(
    'name' => 'John Smith',
    'companyName' => 'Example Company Ltd.',
    'jobTitle' => 'Project Manager',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'phone' => '+1234567890',
);

$result = $teamgate->leads->create($data);

if (!empty($result['success'])) {
    echo 'Thank you for contacting us.';
}
```

Get in-depth information about Teamgate’s REST API and SDK, authentication, parameters, response formats, and errors - [find it all here](http://docs.teamgate.com/reference).